# Installing OpenCV locally

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation, cmake, makefile

I'm trying to install locally and compile my program, with that. I have installed OpenCV-2.4.10 with cmake configuration:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/opencv/installation/ -D CUDA_GENERATION=Kepler -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++-4.9 -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-4.9 -DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF ..
```

in folder `~/opencv/opencv-2.4.10/build`

Then I have set environment variable `export OpenCV_DIR=/lhome/home/golda/opencv/opencv-2.4.10/build`

And was trying to compile my programm with running cmake before. After setting `OpenCV_DIR` cmake has return no errors. Here's a fragment of CMakeCache.txt connected with OpenCV (With full path to my home directory. I replaced it with 
'~'):

```
//Path where debug 3rdpaty OpenCV dependencies are located
OpenCV_3RDPARTY_LIB_DIR_DBG:PATH=

//Path where release 3rdpaty OpenCV dependencies are located
OpenCV_3RDPARTY_LIB_DIR_OPT:PATH=

OpenCV_CONFIG_PATH:FILEPATH=~/opencv/opencv-2.4.10/build

//The directory containing a CMake configuration file for OpenCV.
OpenCV_DIR:PATH=~/opencv/opencv-2.4.10/build

//Path where debug OpenCV libraries are located
OpenCV_LIB_DIR_DBG:PATH=

//Path where release OpenCV libraries are located
OpenCV_LIB_DIR_OPT:PATH=
```

And finally after `make` i got the errors like `undefined reference to 'cv::imread'`

I have tried adding paths:

```
~/opencv/opencv-2.4.10/build/lib:
~/opencv/opencv-2.4.10/include/opencv:
```

respectively to variables: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `INCLUDE_PATH`

My question is what should I do to fix this? I'm lack of ideas now.

Comment: Any reason why you explicitly give the compiler to use ? This seems unnecessary to me, without that, it will just use the default installed compiler.

Comment: I don't use Cmake to build my Opencv apps, I write the makefile so in case that helps, you can check the linking part of the generated makefile, it needs to link with `libopencv_highgui.so` (and `..._core.so` also)

Comment: Yes, there was a reason for all cmake parameters while compiling opencv. If my memory is good compilers versions were changed becouse of Cuda (but I'm not sure) and I had to disable ffmpeg becouse of some other error.

Comment: as for what kebs wrote: I couldn't find in makefile (generated while running cmake for my code and there is no `libopencv_highgui.so` or `..._core.so`)  I have to generate makefile with cmake becouse there is too much dependences and third party libraries to do it manually.

Comment: You should call `make install` from your opencv build, and then use the installation directory as hint for `find_package` in your project. Make sure you use `link_libraries` to link your target to the necessary opencv libraries. By the way, why don't you use the new [OpenCV 3.1](http://opencv.org/opencv-3-1.html)?